# Trying to repair layer paths on opening of a QGIS project from Geopackage

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geopackage

It's some time ago, that I was trying to use the *bad layer handler* in QGIS to change some orphaned layers during project opening. Unfortunately, I was not able to call the *default* *bad layer handler* in advance, to let the user manually handle all the remaining unhandled layers. Honestly, I got stucked.

Yesterday I accidentally found *QgsPathResolver*, which looked very promising to me. I was very delighted as I saw the examples in the API description.

*Some background*: my main aim is to automatically repair a QGIS template project, that was stored together with all it's layers inside of a *GPKG* file. Everytime the *GPKG* file is copied and renamed, the relative layer paths are not automatically updated.

Unfortunately, I couldn't achieve a replacement of the old *GPKG* filename inside the relative paths (see code below).

Can someone shed some light on this? Do I face a bug here or a missing implementation?

BTW: I'm using QGIS 3.12.0 (Windows 10)

```py
from qgis.core import QgsPathResolver,QgsProject
import re

def my_pathpreprocessor(path):
    projectFileName = QgsProject.instance().fileName()
    newPath = path
    if '.gpkg|' in path and path.startswith('./'):
        gpkgProject = re.findall(r'[^/\\]+\.gpkg',projectFileName)[0]
        gpkgProjectPath = re.sub(r'^[^\:]+\:(.+/)[^/]+\.gpkg.+',r'\1',projectFileName)
        print('Old path: '+path)
        if not gpkgProject in path:
            newPath = re.sub(r'[^/\\]+\.gpkg',gpkgProject,path)
            newPath = gpkgProjectPath + newPath[2:]
            print('New path: '+newPath)

    return newPath

QgsPathResolver.setPathPreprocessor(my_pathpreprocessor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's even some time ago that I found a solution for this issue which I would like to share with the community:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsPathResolver,QgsProject,QgsMessageLog,Qgis
import re

class changeGpkgPath:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.gpkgProjectName = ''
        QgsProject.instance().metadataChanged.connect(self.changedMetadata)

    def initGui(self):
        self.processor = QgsPathResolver.setPathPreprocessor(self.path_processor)

    def unload(self):
        QgsPathResolver.removePathPreprocessor(self.processor)

    def changedMetadata(self):
        self.gpkgProjectName = ''
        m = re.search('[^/]+\.gpkg',QgsProject.instance().fileName(),flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        if m:
            self.gpkgProjectName = m.group(0)

    def path_processor(self,path):
        # Replacing GPKG datasources if project is stored in GPKG
        if self.gpkgProjectName:
            if re.search('[^/]+\.gpkg',path,flags=re.IGNORECASE):
                if not re.search(self.gpkgProjectName,path,flags=re.IGNORECASE):
                    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('---------------------------------------------','GPKG',Qgis.Info)
                    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Replace Layer Source: %s' % path,'GPKG',Qgis.Info)
                    path = re.sub('[^/]+\.gpkg',self.gpkgProjectName,path,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
                    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('with: %s' % path,'GPKG',Qgis.Info)

        return path
```

With this plugin (*changeGpkgPath*) I keep my projects and data together and prevent layers getting orphaned. Copying or renaming GPKG projects and loosing data is a problem of the past.